# How to get corresponding pair regarding to a given value from a sorted vector of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I need to get the corresponding pair regarding a given value from a sorted vector of pair container. using 'binary search'. how to do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<pair<int,int>> values;
    values.push_back(make_pair(6,9));
    values.push_back(make_pair(2,5));
    values.push_back(make_pair(12,15));

    sort(values.begin(), values.end()); // sorting the vector according to 'first' value

    /*then the vector be like [(2,5), (6,9), (12,15)]*/
    /*assume : no duplicate or overlapped pairs*/

    /* I need to implement a function to get the corresponding pair related to a given value using 'binary search' method*/
    /*eg:
      if given_value = 7, then function should be return (6,7)
      if given_value = 10, then function shold be return NULL
      how i do this. is there a predefined way to do this ? */
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for std::lower_bound?

Comment: return (a,b) if ((a<=given_value) && (given_value>=b)). otherwise return NULL.
is std::lower_bound support this? @JVApen

Comment: Just in case, you need to implement binary search yourself: there are plenty of books/online resources on how to do that. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) with a custom comparator:

```cpp
std::optional<std::pair<int,int>> find(const std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& vec, int searched) {
  auto it = std::lower_bound(cbegin(vec), cend(vec), std::pair<int, int>{searched, 0}, [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {return a.first < b.first;});
  if(it == cend(vec) || searched < it->first) { // nothing found, return nullopt
    return {};
    // alt: return cend(vec);
  }
  return {*it}; // return value wrapped in optional
  // alt: return it;
}
```

Note: This requires C++17 for the optional. You can also just return the iterator if you found something an do the comparison at the caller (see alternatives in the code above).

Comment: Thx, just read the name and assumed. lower_bound does that what I wanted

Comment: This won't work either, because the condition is wrong. Use return `a.second < b.first` and `it->first > searched` instead.

Comment: And you should mention, that this requires at least C++17 because of `optional`.

Comment: @Olaf thx, I missread the question at first and then did a rushed job on the correction. I disagree a bit regarding the first one, it should be equivalent since there are no overlapping intervals and I think it more obvious that the current test works correctly if we have two touching intervals.